# Value used after move?

Tags: rust

My code:

```rust
fn add(&mut self, key: &str, path: std::path::PathBuf) {
    self.key.push(key.to_string());
    self.path.push(path);
    if key == "img" {
        self.img.push(self.create_img(path))
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/software/init/image.rs:44:27
   |
44 |             self.img.push(self.create_img(path))
   |             -------- ---- ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
   |             |        |
   |             |        first borrow later used by call
   |             first mutable borrow occurs here

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `path`
  --> src/software/init/image.rs:44:43
   |
40 |     fn add(&mut self, key: &str, path: std::path::PathBuf) {
   |                                  ---- move occurs because `path` has type `std::path::PathBuf`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
41 |         self.key.push(key.to_string());
42 |         self.path.push(path);
   |                        ---- value moved here
43 |         if key == "img" {
44 |             self.img.push(self.create_img(path))
   |                                           ^^^^ value used here after move
```

Comment: ownership of path is moved to self.path.push()

Comment: @enno.void ok but i tried many trick for fix my bug, but nothing can you say more ?

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly hard to reason about this code without other methods, but the following code should work (or at least be closer to working solution):

```rust
fn add(&mut self, key: &str, path: std::path::PathBuf) {
    self.key.push(key.to_string());
    // Here, path must be explicitly cloned because of move semantics.
    self.path.push(path.clone());
    if key == "img" {
        // Sometimes compiler cannot determine dependencies of compound
        // statement, so with `img` bounding `img` we un-borrow `self`
        // (if `create_img` returns owned type). Otherwise you need some
        // reference counter like std::rc::Rc.
        let img = self.create_img(path);
        self.img.push(img);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can probably avoid unnecessary cloning of `path` using `self.path.push(&path)`. This is because `PathBuf::push` doesn't require a `PathBuf` value, it accepts everything that implements `AsRef<Path>`, including a reference.

Comment: Good point! I actually thought that `self.path` is `Vec<PathBuf>`, but you probably correct indeed.